# Почему std::find не использует мой operator==?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Я реализовал свою перегрузку `operator==` для сравнения своего `std::pair<...>` с `std::string`. Но по какой-то причине компилятор не может найти эту перегрузку. С чем это может быть связано?

Код для воспроизведения ошибки:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

typedef std::pair<std::string, int> RegPair;

bool operator==(const RegPair& lhs, const std::string& rhs)
{
    return lhs.first == rhs;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<RegPair> sequence;
    std::string foo("foo");
    std::find(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), foo);
}
```

Текст ошибки:

- GNU GCC:

  > error: no match for 'operator==' in '__first. __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* with _Iterator = std::pair, std::allocator >, int>*, _Container = std::vector, std::allocator >, int>, std::allocator, std::allocator >, int> > > == __val'
- clang:

  > error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::pair, int>' and 'std::basic_string const')

---

*Данный вопрос является свободным переводом «[Why isn't std::find() using my operator==?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7287224/2553424)».*

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7287224/2553424

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ответ по ссылке, с которой был сделан перевод, неверен/неточен. ADL-поиск никак не заменяет/не исключает обычный поиск, а лишь дополняет его.

Правильное описание ситуации заключается в следующем:

1. Обычный поиск выполняется из места вызова оператора `==` из определения шаблона функции `std::find` в стандартной библиотеке. Он находит только те имена, которые видны из этого места.

   Понятно, что оттуда приведенное определение оператора `==` не видно.
2. ADL-поиск выполняется в *ассоциированных* и только в *ассоциированных* пространствах имен и видит эти пространства имен такими, каким они стали на момент *вызова* функции `std::find` в вызывающем коде. Набор ассоциированных пространств имен строится в соответствии с правилами, описанными [6.4.2/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.argdep#2).

   В данном случае из точки вызова `std::find` приведенное определение оператора `==` прекрасно видно. Но это определение сделано в *глобальном* пространстве имен. А ассоциированным для ADL в данном случае является только пространство `std`, ибо оба аргумента сравнения принадлежат пространству `std`. Поэтому глобальное пространство имен не рассматривается ADL и данное определение не находится.

   Утверждение о том, что ADL якобы прекращает дальнейший поиск определений `operator ==` именно из-за того, что какие-то определения `operator ==` уже найдены внутри `std` - неверно. ADL всегда ищет имена только внутри ассоциированных пространств имен. В отличие от обычного lookup, ADL никогда не расширяет область поиска за пределы ассоциированных пространств имен, независимо от того, найдено там что-либо или нет.

Ту же проблему можно проиллюстрировать следующим маленьким примером

```
namespace N
{
  struct S {};
}

template <typename T> void foo(T a) 
{
  bar(a);                         // 1
}

void bar(N::S s) {}

int main()
{
  N::S a;
  foo(a);                         // 2
}
```

При таком порядке объявлений обычный поиск имен находит имена, видные из точки 1, а ADL поиск находит имена, видные из точки 2, *но только в ассоциированных пространствах имен*. Глобальное пространство имен ассоциированным не является, поэтому объявление `void bar(N::S s)` не находится и код не компилируется.

В исходном варианте, если мы каким-то образом "притянем за уши" глобальное пространство имен в качестве ассоциированного для ADL, то данный оператор `==` сразу начнет находиться через ADL. Например, объявим в глобальном пространстве имен некий фиктивный тип, приводимый к `std::string` и используем именно его в качестве ключа для поиска

```
...

struct S : std::string
{
    using std::string::string;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<RegPair> sequence;
    S foo("foo");
    std::find(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), foo);
}
```

Определение оператора сравнения при этом менять не надо. Код сразу начнет компилироваться и использовать данный оператор сравнения.

Другой вариант внешне "невинной" замены, который заставит код компилироваться - сделать второй член пары типом из глобального пространства имен

```
struct X {};
typedef std::pair<std::string, X> RegPair;
```

Больше ничего менять не надо - этого уже достаточно для того, чтобы ассоциировать глобальное пространство имен для ADL.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключается в том, что `std::find` является шаблонной функцией, а потому при поиске `operator==` в дело вступает ADL ([поиск, зависимый от типов аргументов](http://goran-dev.blogspot.ru/2011/10/adl.html)).

Оба аргумента функции (`std::pair` и `std::string`) находятся в одном и том же пространстве имён (`::std`), поэтому ADL начинает поиск именно в нём. При этом достаточно, чтобы там был определён хоть какой-то `operator==`, так как сопоставление имён (name lookup) производится до определения подходящих перегрузок.

В связи с тем, что подходящий по имени `operator==` обязательно будет найден (в том же`<string>` объявлен как минимум оператор сравнения `std::string` с чем-то), алгоритм останавливает свою работу. До вашей же перегрузки, расположенной в глобальном пространстве имён (то есть за пределами `::std`), очередь так и не дойдёт.

---

*Данное сообщение является свободным переводом [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7287568/2553424) участника [James McNellis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151292/james-mcnellis).*