# Поиск необъявленной функции для пользовательского и встроенного типов

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
struct A {

};

using Type = A;   // (1)
using Type = int; // (2)

template<typename T>
T x = foo(T{});

auto foo(Type x) {
    return x;
}

int main() {
    x<Type>;
}
```

Почему если закомментировать строку (1), то программа **не** компилируется gcc и clang ([1](https://godbolt.org/z/ZP0dwQ) и [2](https://godbolt.org/z/rFUozc)), а если закомментировать строку (2), то компилируется обоими компиляторами ([3](https://godbolt.org/z/nAzCNw) и [4](https://godbolt.org/z/d4SO88))?

Comment: FYI, на godbolt'е можно несколько компиляторов параллельно повесить на один код....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Имя функции `foo` в данном случае является *зависимым именем* в определении шаблона. Для зависимых имен выполняется [два вида поиска имен](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep.res#1):

1. Обычный поиск имен, видимых из точки определения шаблона.
2. Поиск имен в т.наз. *ассоциированных пространствах имен*, видимых как из точки определения шаблона, так и из точки его инстанцирования. Это пространства имен, ассоциированные с типами аргументов функции.

Это то, что неформально называется "двухфазным поиском имен". При этом важно то, что второй вид поиска ("вторая фаза") выполняется *только* в ассоциированных пространствах имен.

- Встроенные типы не имеют ассоциированных пространств имен вообще. Поэтому если в вашем примере аргумент функции `foo` имеет тип `int`, то второй вид поиска фактически не выполняется вообще. Никаких новых функций найдено не будет. Код является некорректным.
- Пользовательский тип `A` в качестве ассоциированного пространства имен имеет то пространство имен, в котором он объявлен, т.е. глобальное пространство имен. Вторым видом поиска будет сделан поиск в глобальном пространстве имен из точки инстанцирования шаблона и найдена "новая" функция `foo`. Код корректен.

См. также
[Почему std::find не использует мой operator==?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/780186/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-stdfind-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-operator?rq=1)
[Не могу понять что не нравится clang`у](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/886168/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-clang%D1%83)